# Authentication and Authorization soap webservices using wssecurity username token implementation apache cxf

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, ws-security, jbossfuse

I am trying to implement authentication and authorization using WS-Security UsernameToken in my CXF inbound endpoint using SubjectCreatingInterceptor.

I have stored my username, password, and role information in application properties of the JBoss EAP server.

Bean configuration is as below.

endpoints.xml:

```
<bean id="authenticationInterceptor" class="org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.security.authentication.SubjectCreatingInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="authorizationInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.security.SimpleAuthorizingInterceptor">
    <property name="globalRoles" value="testrole"/>
</bean>

<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="auth-endpoint" 
    xmlns:nms="http://tempuri.org/" 
    address="http://localhost:9090/auth/test" 
    endpointName="nms:BasicHttpBinding_IRmsAuthenticationService" 
    serviceName="nms:RmsAuthenticationService" 
    wsdlURL="wsdl/Authentication_1.wsdl" 
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="ws-security.validate.token" value="false" />
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="MESSAGE"/>
    </cxf:properties>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="authenticationInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="authorizationInterceptor" />
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Soap request XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:upm="http://testservices.com">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>testauth</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">testauth@123</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <upm:GetToken2>
        <upm:Token>test</upm:Token>
    </upm:GetToken2>
</soapenv:Body>
```

After triggering the request it is giving the below error:

```
WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain Interceptor for {
http://tempuri.org/}RmsAuthenticationService has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.security.authentication.SubjectCreatingInterceptor.handleMessage(SubjectCreatingInterceptor.java:95) [jbossws-cxf-server-4.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.Final-redhat-1] 
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.security.authentication.SubjectCreatingInterceptor.handleMessage(SubjectCreatingInterceptor.java:61) [jbossws-cxf-server-4.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.3.6.Final-redhat-1] 
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262] 
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262] 
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262] 
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262] 
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70) [cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1129) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1065) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908] 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151-1-redhat]
```

Could you please suggest what is missing. Thanks in advance.

Dear Ricardo, We have tried implementing WSS4J interceptor as you suggested. But we are facing the below issue, WARN  [org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel] (qtp1703888095-358) /auth/test: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SAML_TOKEN
                at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.CXFRequestData.(CXFRequestData.java:39) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.1.12.jar:3.1.12]
                at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:184) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.1.12.jar:3.1.12]
                at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:171) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.1.12.jar:3.1.12]
                at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:80) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.1.12.jar:3.1.12]
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70) [cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.1.5.redhat-630262.jar:3.1.5.redhat-630262]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1129) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1065) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151-1-redhat]
It looks like its not able to initialize the CXFrequestdata java class. We have used util

```
<util:constant
    static-field="org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandlerConstants.ACTION"/>
```

within the constructor-arg while declaring the WSS4JInterceptor bean in order avoid the constants loading in CXFRequestData class. Could you please suggest how we can proceed further. Thank you.!!

Comment: Instead of using JBossWS could you leverage from WSDL4J. Take a look at this example: https://github.com/jboss-fuse/quickstarts/blob/master/cxf/secure-soap/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml

Comment: Could you please help in implementing SubjectCreatingInterceptor, we need the same in our project. Thank you.. !!

Comment: Hi! Take a look at the example I’ve linked in my previous comment. The implementation you’re using is from JBossWS. It’s better to follow the example above because, IMO, suits your environment.